# Is there a good website with lessons to learn HTML?

Tags: html

I am looking for recommendations for a starting website to learn how to write HTML code

Comment: hope you don't mind, i changed the title, because... almost anything having to do with html would involve a browser somehow, no?

Comment: sandbox still sounds weird, though

Comment: YMMV. It's the word I would have used.

Comment: noah, why did you change the question? now it asks for something completely different!

Comment: I realized that the question did not really reflect what I was looking for. Most answerers were hung up on the sandbox, and not giving me HTML direction. The answer from le Dorfier gave both, and I realized how I needed to change the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[start here](http://www.w3schools.com/) at w3schools.com. They provide a niftly little sandbox with sample code for all your web design element questions.

Comment: yay! instead of having to save-and-reload, you just have to click one button! big win! :) -- and on the upside you lose every comfort a decent text editor might give you! double win!! (excuse my sarcasm... bad morning)

Comment: It's probably hard for you to remember that far back, but when you're first learning HTML it sometimes helps to have a code fragment to start with that actually works. You're probably one of the lucky young guys whose first code *was* html.

Comment: +1 I still occasionally go back to w3schools when I forget something. Its not a place for the cool-kids to go, but its a great learning resource

Comment: le dorfier... i don't even think of writing html as coding. but you misunderstood me! i'm not against examples, i'm against the online-editor-thingy

Comment: w3schools is the ultimate starting point to many web related technologies.

Comment: Citing W3Schools as a place to learn HTML is like citing McDonalds as a way to learn how to cook. Please read here. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: I'd stay away from W3Schools because it's only for amateurs.
If you want a good website for HTML 4.01 / XHTML 1.0 then try http://www.htmldog.com/ - they have great and professional tutorials

Comment: W3schools has lots of out-dated content. Check out this W3schools Alternative http://www.snoopcode.com

Answer (score 5):

This question seems a bit weird... what do you mean by "sandbox"?

Usually you simply practice writing HTML by using a text editor and opening the local file from the browser.

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping to find a site that would give immediate feedback, rather than having to save and reload

Comment: there are text editors that support live previews of what you type.

Answer (score 1):

**Notepad + any broswer** - This works well for me. Just save your file to .htm

Or if you want, get FireFox or Opera, go to any site (say, stackoverflow.com or w3schools.com), view the source, edit away and then apply the changes. Don't worry, the changes only affect a single tab and doesn't changes anything on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox for HTML? you must be kidding.There are no chances of getting hurt even if your HTML goes wrong. So you don't need a sandbox.

Use any decent editor which gives a two-tab view for Source-code and Quick-view, and you are done. You can use MS Frontpage or EditPlus, both offer these features. You don't need to save to see the effect.

**Please don't clog the bandwidth for just testing and debugging HTML. It ain't worth it.**

Answer (score 1):

Some things don't work with Javascript when served from file:// due to security protocols, and sometimes it can be too much of a pain trying to get a webhost up and running for experimenting with stuff.

http://www.webdevout.net/test

I have found to be a convenient playground tool, with the benefit when you mangle something up and you want help to work out what you did wrong you can post the link to somebody and they can see what you've done without you needing to worry about security, hosting, or firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say check out these video tutorials from net tuts. It starts off with the very basics and then moves on to more in depth stuff. The tutorials are organized as a 30-day course, where they'll mail you a link to a video tutorial each day. The idea being you'll have learnt html/css within 30 days. But you really don't need to sign up for the mailing service, just take it at your own pace.

http://learncss.tutsplus.com/